# Unity 3D Pixelate individual 3D objects but retain resolution over distance

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I've been doing research around how to create a pixilated effect in Unity for 3D objects. I came across the following tutorials that were useful to me:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dpNhymnBDQw
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z8xB7i3W4CE

For the most part, it is what I am looking for, where I can pixelate certain objects in my scene (I don't want to render all objects as pixelated).

The effect, however, works based of the screen resolution so when you are closer to objects they become less pixelated and vice versa:

[image: Cube on the right is of lower resolution (made of less pixels)]

*Notice how the cube on the right consists of less pixels as it is further away.*

Do you perhaps have an idea as to how you would keep the resolution of the pixelated object consistent regardless of distance to them such as below (this effect was done in photoshop, I am unaware as to how to actually implement it):
[image]

I'm not sure if this even is possible with the method provided by most pixelart methods.

I was thinking maybe if you could use a shader per object in the scene that would render the pixelated object then you could do some fancy shader math to fix the resolution keeping it consistent per object, however I have no idea as to how you would even render a pixel effect with just a shader. (The only method I can think of is what is described in the videos in which you render the objects onto a smaller  resolution via render texture then upscale to screen resolution, which you can't really do with a shader assigned to a material).

Another thought I had was to render each object separately using a separate camera for each object I wanted pixelated, then I could set the camera to be a fixed distance away from the object and blit the render together onto the main camera. This way since each pixelated object is rendered individually with their own camera at a fixed distance, they will retain a fixed pixel resolution regardless of distance from the main camera. (Essentially you can think of it as converting each object into a sprite and rendering that sprite in the scene, thus keeping the resolution of each object consistent despite distance) But this obviously has its own set of problems from performance, to different orientations etc...

Any ideas?

Ideally I am able to specify the resolution I want for a specific 3D object in my scene to be pixelated to and it retains that over any distance. This way I have the flexibility to have different objects rendered at different resolutions.

I should mention that I am using the Universal Render Pipeline at the moment with a custom render feature to achieve my current pixelated effect through downscaling a render texture and upscaling to screen resolution, in which I can change the resolution of the downscaled texture.